# Kali Linux kernel headers for 4.14.71-v6

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, linux-headers

I am trying to install kernel headers version 4.14.71-v6 (uname -r) for Kali Linux. I already did the common commands...

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
apt install linux-headers-generic
alt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

...with and without option `-y`

Also did reboots. I searched the repos by apt search 4.14. I took a look onto http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/, no success at all.

I've seen on http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/ are kernel-headers for 4.18 and 4.19, but the upgrade is distributing versions only up to my 4.14.x

Does anybody have an idea what to do?

Comment: Everyone: please stop blindly voting to close Kali questions as dupes of the "why is Kali hard" one. The OP is showing effort, and asking a question that is on topic.

Comment: I notice that Kali provided kernels all have "-kali" in their name. How come yours has "-v6" instead? Was it provided by Kali in the first place?

Comment: Is it your issue that your system doesn't upgrade the kernel to 4.18 when you do the updates, therefore you are trying to install the old kernel headers (4.14) to match your current kernel?

Comment: @A.B Good catch. Probably Kali for rpi/arm with a slight modified kernel.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro quite possible, but OP has to explain it whatever the reason. From OP's link, Kali does provide armhf kernels also having "-kali".

Comment: @A.B That is the problem with these Kali questions....

Comment: @A.B https://github.com/Re4son/re4son-kernel-builder

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, then -v6 might be for armel / arm v6. Anyway the question is incomplete...

Comment: @terdon The problem is that "Kali is hard" seems yet to be the best recommendation. People seem to not known what they are dealing with, and that a Kali setup is a mess by default in several ways compared to the alternatives. This seems to be a Kali with an altered kernel.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `uname -a`

Comment: The problem is I can't install Linux headers because they are not given in repository. So I tried to find some way to install them. My distribution is the arm/rpi0 from offensive-security hp. Btw: I know Kali is not for absolute beginners - but for me it is the next step.

Comment: i also saw the offensive repository while investigating, but it seems the kernel was installed with the project I indicate in the answer...Kali setups are such a contrived mess that is easier to install each new ,major version than trying to update them. I prefer often to install my tools in Debian than dealing w/ Kali.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not finding the headers for your kernel version, in the official distribution repository, because you are dealing with a Kali setup using a custom made kernel version.

Whist we do not have all data, from you `uname -r`, it leds me to suspect it was made using these scripts/tools https://github.com/Re4son/re4son-kernel-builder  ; it also leads me to speculate, after a bit of detective work, that maybe you have a Raspberry PI/ARM v6 device.

In this case, the easier option is either to reinstall a new version, or even better, choosing a more user friendly Linux distribution.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. It's the rpi0-version. I found another way installing the Re4son-kernel. It got headers installed by default.